# Firefox randomly not reacting

Tags: 14.04, firefox, resize

sometimes on my Ubuntu 14.10 machine Firefox 33 hangs. This means that although performing clicks or keyboard shortcuts the window content doesn't change. When I resize the window, everything is fine again, until the next "hang".

Do you have an idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: Is it a hang, or a long, slow delay to respond?

Comment: It's a hang. The title Bar is the only thing that changed (when hovering)

Comment: I get odd lazy responses, which I solve by clearing the cache files.

Comment: just cleared the cache to test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many "Firefox" problems are caused by problematic themes, extensions, or plugins. To quickly check for these potential causes, follow the steps in the Standard diagnostic - Firefox article. The Mozi kb article link give below will give you the detailed information of various Firefox hangs and its fix.

http://kb.mozillazine.org/Firefox_hangs

Note: Me faced similar issues with scrips in google drive not responding or due to Adobe flash player either hangs or crashes in Firefox.

Comment: I face precisely the same issue - nothing works until window resized.  Which part of this answer actually solved the problem for the OP?